# jQuery datepicker onChangeMonthYear event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to build an app based on jQuery date picker. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf6sD/2/. There is a `onChangeMonthYear` even mentioned in the options, which is supposed to do a simple alert when user changes month or year either through the drop downs or the navigation buttons on the top left and top right.

However, the alert doesn't appear when I am changing month or year either way.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong, and how do I capture the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have onChangeMonthYearType

Change it to this:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,instance) {
        alert("h");
    }
```

Comment: Check this - http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear. You might be accessing old DOcs. Previous versions

Comment: Dunno, now it is indeed showing `onChangeMonthYear`, but when I saw it previously, it was `onChangeMonthYearType`!

Comment: Yeah. They keep changing the versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onChangeMonthYear` not `onChangeMonthYearType`,

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,instance) {
        alert("h");
}
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf6sD/4/)**

Comment: So It is deprecated now i guess